# Getting error while searching documents from cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have stored all articles in cloud firestore and now im searching a article from cloud firestore.
Search is working fine but when i tap on a article to go on detail screen to read more. i m getting this error : type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'

this is my search screen :

```
class SearchService {
searchByName(String searchField) {
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('articles')
    .where('searchKey',
        isEqualTo: searchField.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())
    .get();
 }
}

 class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_SearchScreenState createState() => new _SearchScreenState();
   }

 class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
 var queryResultSet = [];
 var tempSearchStore = [];

initiateSearch(value) {
if (value.length == 0) {
  setState(() {
    queryResultSet = [];
    tempSearchStore = [];
  });
}

  if (queryResultSet.length == 0 && value.length == 1) {
  SearchService().searchByName(value).then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; ++i) {
      queryResultSet.add(docs.docs[i].data());
      setState(() {
        tempSearchStore.add(queryResultSet[i]);
      });
    }
  });
} else {
  queryResultSet.forEach((element) {
    if (element['title'].toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()) ==
        true) {
      if (element['title'].toLowerCase().atIndex(value.toLowerCase()) ==
          0) {
        setState(() {
          tempSearchStore.add(element);
        });
      }
    }
  });
  }
  if (tempSearchStore.length == 0 && value.length > 1) {
  setState(() {});
  }
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: new AppBar(
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: CustomColors.blackColor),
    title: TextField(
      onChanged: (val) {
        initiateSearch(val);
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Search here',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: CustomColors.greyColor,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: tempSearchStore.map((element) {
      return SearchResults(
        data: element,
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
 }
 }
```

this my search item:

```
class SearchResults extends StatelessWidget {
final data;

const SearchResults({this.data});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var readTime = readingTime(data['desc']);
return InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    Get.to(
      DetailScreen(
        articles: data,
      ),
    );
  },
  child: Container(
    height: Get.mediaQuery.size.height * 0.24,
    width: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.8,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.65,
              ),
              child: Text(
                data['title'],
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                  color: CustomColors.blackColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Image.network(
              data['imageUrl'],
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

}

this is my detail screen to view full article:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final DocumentSnapshot articles;

final ArticlesController articlesController = Get.find<ArticlesController>();

DetailScreen({@required this.articles});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: CustomColors.blackColor),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            toBeginningOfSentenceCase(
              articles.data()['title'],
            ),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: CustomColors.blackColor,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 15, right: 30, left: 30, bottom: 15),
            child: SelectableText(
              articles.data()['desc'],
              toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: true, selectAll: true),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                letterSpacing: 1,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

docs.docs[i] is a DocumentSnapshot

But docs.docs[i].data() is a Map<String, dynamic>

You have add lists (queryResultList and other) as Map but detailscreen field is DocumentSnapshot.

Comment: I know list in detail screen is type of DocumentSnapshot and list of search articles is dynamic.. but this is my question, like how can i make get searched article in documentsnapshot.

Comment: You must indexing first , but in firebase this is a high costly . You can use Algolia. https://itnext.io/full-text-search-in-flutter-with-algolia-firestore-cloud-functions-with-optimization-54004d727ad1